# Use jq extract two values and build new output

Tags: jq

Looking to extract values from api_http array. I am looking for output that looks like the following. Each element should have the name and the url value attached a key called api.

```
{ "name": "lookproduct1", "api": "http://testapi.api.com"}
{ "name": "lookproduct2", "api": "http://testapi2.api.com"}
{ "name": "lookproduct3", "api": "http://testapi3.api.com"}
{ "name": "lookproduct4", "api": "http://testapi4.api.com"}
```

**the JSON data:**

```
{
    "meta": {
      "details": {
        "value": "Details"
      },
      "network": {
        "label": "Network:",
        "value": "test"
      },
      "title": {
        "value": "Test Report"
      },
      "update": {
        "label": "Validation last update:",
        "value": "2020-07-15 17:40 UTC"
      }
    },
    "report": {
      "api_http": [
        [
          {
            "html_name": "Product 1",
            "name": "lookproduct1",
            "rank": 3
          },
          "http://testapi.api.com",
          "GB",
          "TEST"
        ],
        [
            {
              "html_name": "Product 2",
              "name": "lookproduct2",
              "rank": 3
            },
            "http://testapi2.api.com",
            "GB",
            "TEST"
          ],
          [
            {
              "html_name": "Product 3",
              "name": "lookproduct3",
              "rank": 3
            },
            "http://testapi3.api.com",
            "GB",
            "TEST"
          ],
          [
            {
              "html_name": "Product 4",
              "name": "lookproduct4",
              "rank": 3
            },
            "http://testapi.api.com",
            "GB",
            "TEST"
          ]
      ]
    }
 }
```

I got the following, but unsure to extract those final two values and create the new output.

```
.report[] | .[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.report.api_http[]|{name:values[0]["name"],api:values[1]}
```

My output is:

```
{
  "name": "lookproduct1",
  "api": "http://testapi.api.com"
}
{
  "name": "lookproduct2",
  "api": "http://testapi2.api.com"
}
{
  "name": "lookproduct3",
  "api": "http://testapi3.api.com"
}
{
  "name": "lookproduct4",
  "api": "http://testapi.api.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the -c command-line option in conjunction with the following jq filter:

```
.report.api_http[]
| {name: .[0].name, api: .[1]}
```